# Get width of element with no css or width attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Scenario: You have a div with some text, this div has no css width, no jquery width, no width attribute assigned to it in any way. However it has a width due to the content that is inside it, this is undefined, reports as "null" in jQuery. My question is: is there any way to retireve the width of this div?

Comment: @ThomasReggi:  my experiments suggest that such a `div` does in fact report a width when using jQuery.  [here's a simple example at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/TEEj3/).  Maybe there is something special about your scenario -- can you elaborate?

Comment: @Thomas , are you adding that div dynamically ?? post your html , jquery .width you definetly get you the width.

Comment: @Thomas post your complete html or make an example at jsfiddle so that we can fix your problem or we can learn a new thing....if this is a different case.

Comment: I believe an unstyled `div` doesn't get it's width from the content within it but will get it's height from that. So I believe the default width of a `div` is the width of it's container, maybe you could grab that?

Comment: it works thanks (missed the class dot) ty!

Comment: @thomas thats cool , we always make that mistake either forgets dot or # symbols....

Comment: @subhaze you are wrong , even though you don't specify width , it takes it parents and browser reservers that width for that so that element will have the dom property called width for sure , so  you can get the value through javascript...

Comment: @gov basically... that's what I said, and didn't say it wouldn't have a width but that the divs **content** wouldn't define it's width however it's **container** / **parent** would...   http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/KRyeg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with jquery you can do below

```
$('#id').width()
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(element).width()` should give you the actual width. With `$(element).outerWidth(includeMargin)` you can even get the width including padding, border, and, if desired, the margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the offsetWidth like this:

```
element.offsetWidth
```

or with a ref in React

```
elementRef.current.offsetWidth
```